# Checked checkboxes to comma separated list with word "and" at the end in C#

Tags: c#, checkbox

I'm have a few checkboxes nestled inside a WinForms panel. When the checkboxes are checked, I want to create a comma separated list, but with the word "and" before the last checkbox text value.

Here is the code I currently have...which is executed from a single event handler shared by all checkboxes:

```
    string checkboxes = " ";
    foreach (Control c in MyPanel.Controls)
    {
        if (c is CheckBox && (c as CheckBox).Checked)
            checkboxes += (c as CheckBox).Text;
    }
    checkboxes = string.Join(", ", checkboxes.Take(checkboxes.Count() - 1)) + (checkboxes.Count() > 1 ? " and " : "") + checkboxes.LastOrDefault();
    Console.WriteLine(checkboxes + "are checked");
```

I have the following checkboxes:

```
_Item A
_Item B
_Item C
_Item D
```

If, for example, Item A and B are checked, I want it to spit out "**Item A and B are checked**".

If Item A, B and D are checked... "**Item A, Item B and Item D are checked**"

However, with my current code, it's doing something similar to this:

> , I, t, e, m, A, I, t, e, m, B, I, t, e, m and D are checked.

If someone could point me into the right direction, I'd much appreciate it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
string checkboxes = " ";
foreach (Control c in MyPanel.Controls)
{
    if (c is CheckBox && (c as CheckBox).Checked)
        checkboxes += (c as CheckBox).Text.Split().Last();
}
checkboxes=String.Concat(checkboxes.OrderBy(c => c);
checkboxes = string.Join(", ", checkboxes.Take(checkboxes.Count() - 1)) + (checkboxes.Length > 1 ? " and " : "") + checkboxes.LastOrDefault();
if (checkboxes.Length>1)
     checkboxes = checkboxes.Remove(0, 2);
Console.WriteLine("Items " + checkboxes + " are checked");
```

Comment: Unfortunately, your suggestion is still injecting unnecessary commas.

Comment: @Spencer: What is the output you are getting with this code?

Comment: If A, B and C are checked, it will return: "Items  , C, B and Aare checked"...If two are checked: "Items  , B and Aare checked"...also is there anyway to flip the item text values? It outputs them backwards from C to A instead of A to C.

Comment: Hmmm, it still doesn't seem to be working for me... "Items , C, B and A are checked".

Comment: Changing the `Remove(0,1)` to `Remove(0,2)` semi-works; however, if just one checkbox is checked, then it returns: "Items are checked" instead of "Items A are checked".

Comment: @Spencer: That is because checkboxes has value of 1 character only. Changed in my answer.

Comment: Great....now just one more thing! If only one checkbox is checked, then the world "and" should not be in the string anywhere...but it is returning "Items and A are checked".

Comment: @Spencer: Change `checkboxes.Count()` to `checkboxes.Length` as in my answer.

Comment: Great, that worked! Now...do you know if it's possible to reverse the checkbox text labels from A to C, instead of C to A (as I mentioned earlier)?

Comment: @Spencer: Edited my answer. Added a line to order the checkbox names.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a poor man's implementation using LINQ and `String.Join`. This prepends an "and" to the last item first and then simply joins the results together to make a comma-separated list:

```
//get a list of the text of the checked checkboxes
var checkedNames = MyPanel.Controls.OfType<CheckBox>().Cast<CheckBox>()
    .Where(c => c.Checked).Select(c => c.Text).ToList();

//boundary cases
if(checkedNames.Count == 0)
    return "Nothing is checked";
else if(checkedNames.Count == 1)
    return checkedNames[0] + " is checked";    

//add an "and" to the last one
checkedNames[checkedNames.Count - 1] = "and " + checkedNames[checkedNames.Count - 1];

//join them up into a comma-separated list
return String.Join(" ,", checkedNames) + " are checked";
```